# What ways are there to organize the webpack code?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I don't know if it fits the question, but I've been reading some codes and because I'm learning about webpack now I came across this code structure below in some of them, and I'm wondering what kind of organized structure is this and what do i need to know to start organizing my code with this structure?

```js
require = function () {

    //Some code

}()({
    1: [function (require, module, exports) {
        function hello(){
          console.log('hello');
        }
        module.exports = hello;
    }, {}],
    
    2: [function (require, module, exports) {
      //Some code
    }, {}],
    
    3: [function (require, module, exports) {
      //Another code
    }, {}],

    4:...,

})
```

Comment: Is this code from something *compiled* via Webpack (i.e. Webpack's output)? If so, *you* don't do this.

Comment: @crashmstr Yes, i was reading some scripts and i noticed that they worked with webpack in this way, and it intrigued me, because of the organization of the code.

Comment: That is because `require` is not something a browser "understands", so Webpack, in processing the code and all of the `require` and `import` and other module "stuff", makes it "work". As a developer who uses Webpack, you generally do not need to know anything about how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not webpack, this is [Browserify](https://browserify.org/), and the structure is this:

```js
(function() {
    function r(e, n, t) {
        function o(i, f) {
            if (!n[i]) {
                if (!e[i]) {
                    var c = "function" == typeof require && require;
                    if (!f && c)
                        return c(i, !0);
                    if (u)
                        return u(i, !0);
                    var a = new Error("Cannot find module '" + i + "'");
                    throw a.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
                    a
                }
                var p = n[i] = {
                    exports: {}
                };
                e[i][0].call(p.exports, function(r) {
                    var n = e[i][1][r];
                    return o(n || r)
                }, p, p.exports, r, e, n, t)
            }
            return n[i].exports
        }
        for (var u = "function" == typeof require && require, i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
            o(t[i]);
        return o
    }
    return r
}
)()({
    1: [function(require, module, exports) {
    }
    , {}]
}, {}, [1]);
```